# Atomic, asynchronous HTTP file POST with sensible feedback?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, http, macos, upload

I've just started development on Macs and have found Cocoa to be a useful and thoughtful framework, but its HTTP functionality has me puzzled.

I have an NSURLConnection object to download a file from my webserver using the HTTP GET method. NSURLConnect's asynchronous connection is great, I get plenty of feedback, I get each chunk received as a new NSData object that I can use to atomically rebuild the file on the client end and, importantly, provide the user with a progress report: [myData length].

Uploads, however, are nowhere near as neat. You can either stick a synchronous request in its own thread or call an asynchronous request (which I believe spawns its own thread), but neither provide you with any useful feedback. There's no delegates to request data or even let me know when data is being sent. Presumably this limits me to files smaller than available memory.

My question is, therefore, is there a simple and elegant solution to HTTP POST file uploads using Cocoa that provides a good deal of feedback and the ability to read files part-by-part, rather than all at once? Or should I write my own class from low-level networking functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not let them go in their own threads? You could use NSOperation to ensure that you're not creating/managing/etc. tons of threads you don't need. What kind of data feedback do you expect from a POST operation?

Comment: The amount of data I've uploaded thus far. I'm dealing with potentially large files, so I need to provide the user with a progress bar or like. Threading isn't so much the issue, it's more the ability to load files-part-by-part and get feedback.

Props for the absurdly fast reply!

Comment: Ah, okay! I probably would just roll something myself. I'm pretty sure I saw a decent class for NSURL with POST functionality once, but I don't remember where... maybe someone will add a decent answer, but you might want to google it a bit. I remember it took me a little digging to find it myself.

Comment: Asking StackOverflow was the last resort after a weekend of Googling for it :) Thanks, Jason.

Comment: Oh wow, I may have it bookmarked somewhere, I'll check :)

Comment: Ok, how about this: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.19/19.04/CocoaApplications/index.html -- it's definitely roll-your-own, but it seems really well thought out, and somebody else rolled it for you :) Looks like it should be easy to hack up to meet your needs as well...

Comment: A quick scan of that site has, I think, given me the answer; I should be reading and posting x bytes of the file at a time from disk at the receiver end and using my web script to reassemble, rather than relying on cocoa to do it for me. Using some of the tips from that link and what I've got already should sort me out. Cheers again!

Comment: If you're uploading something from a file on disk, definitely look at the CFHTTPMessage API (in CFNetwork.framework on iPhone, CoreServices.framework on Mac). That allows you to specify a stream for the body data of your request instead of a chunk of data. That way you can instantiate an NSInputStream (or a CFReadStreamRef) from the file directly, and simply provide that to the CFHTTPMessage as its body.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) framework. I haven't used it for uploading but it looks like it has more feedback and the usage is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to go with CFNetwork functions instead of NSURLConnection. There appears to be a bit more flexibility in async notifications and in specific features (authentication for instance). Unfortunately it's a bit more complicated (run loops for instance blow my mind) so I recommend you read the CFNetwork reference guide if you go this route:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html

Here's a snippet of code from my POST routine, FWIW:

```
// Create our URL
CFStringRef url = CFSTR("Submit");
CFURLRef myURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, url, baseUrl);

// Create the message request (POST)
CFStringRef requestMethod = CFSTR("POST");
CFHTTPMessageRef myRequest = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestMethod, myURL, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);

// Connect the read socket to the HTTP request stream
CFReadStreamRef myReadStream = CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, myRequest, readStream);
// TODO: why does this have to be done?
succ &= CFReadStreamSetClient(myReadStream,
  kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted | kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered,
  (CFReadStreamClientCallBack) &MyReadCallBack, &myClientContext);
CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(myReadStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
succ &= CFReadStreamOpen(myReadStream);
```

Answer (score 2):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) was originally designed just for this purpose (tracking POST progress), since in the 2.x API, this isn't possible with NSURLConnection. It will definitely be easier to integrate than rolling your own with CFNetwork, and you get lots of other stuff for free (e.g. progress tracking across multiple requests, resuming downloads etc). :)

If the files you are uploading are large, be sure to look at the options for streaming directly from disk, so you don't have to hold the data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're quite correct that NSURLConnection is weak here. The most flexible approach that I would recommend is [CocoaAsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/). It means rolling your own HTTP, which is unfortunate, but in most cases not that difficult. [CocoaHTTPServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) demonstrates how to build a full HTTP server on top of CocoaAsyncSocket, and may have a lot of useful code for your problem. I've found both of these very useful.

Another approach that may be worth investigating is WebKit. Create an invisible WebView, and loadRequest: a POST. I haven't dug into whether the estimatedChange notification system includes the time to upload or only the time to download, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the HTTPMessage section of [my toolkit repository on github](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master) for a simple ObjC wrapper around CFHTTPMessageRef; among other things it'll hand you an NSInputStream object, which saves you thinking about plain-C callback functions.

Depending on what you're reading, you may want to take a look at the StreamingXMLParser section of the same repository for an XML (and HTML) parser which will parse data directly from said NSInputStream on your behalf.